# Is it possible get all context nodes used to evalute xpath result?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

Is it possible get all context nodes used to evalute xpath result ?
In below code:

```
test_xml = """
<r>
    <a/>
    <a>
        <b/>
    </a>
    <a>
        <b/>
    </a>
</r>
"""
test_root = lxml.etree.fromstring(test_xml)
res = test_root.xpath("//following-sibling::*[1]/b")
for node in res:
    print test_root.getroottree().getpath(node)
```

Result are:

```
/r/a[2]/b
/r/a[3]/b
```

Is it possible to get all context nodes used in above xpath evaluation:

```
/r/a[1] /r/a[2] /r/a[2]/b
```

and for second result:

```
/r/a[2] /r/a[3]/b /r/a[3]/b
```

?
When using  child axis I could get those nodes from working on

```
element_tree.getpath(elem)
```

but what abouth other axes ?

TIA, regards

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "Used to evaluate xpath result".

Comment: I mean seqeuence of context nodes per each level of xpath query (as spearated by axis) when result is found.
For //following-sibling::*[1]/b I would expect three nodes:
1. "root element" where avaluation start
2. Element being following-sibling::*[1] of "root element"
3. last one is exact <b> element which is result of query

Comment: so essentially you are trying to get all of the ancestor nodes for a particular xml element?

Comment: @user258541: There is a conceptual problem with your question: starting `//` operator would be expanded to `/descendat-or-self::node()/`. That means after document root the whole tree will be trasverse (and every node will be an "in context" node for next step).

Answer (score 1):

I reversed the xpath for each stage to get which items would be evaluated in the result:

```
for node in res:
    j = node.xpath('./parent::*')[0]
    k = j.xpath('./preceding-sibling::*[1]')[0]
    # You didn't specify these but they were used in the evaluation
    ancestors = k.xpath('./ancestor::*')
    for item in [node, j, k] + ancestors:
        print item.getroottree().getpath(item)
    print '\n\n'
```

gives me:

/r/a[2]/b, /r/a[2], /r/a[1], /r

/r/a[3]/b, /r/a[3], /r/a[2], /r

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you are trying to just get the ancestor nodes of particular nodes. The XPATH expression for this would be:

```
//particular-element/ancestor::*
```

such as:

```
/r/a[2]/b/ancestor::*
```